# Commutativity of endomorphism rings of direct sums

Tags: modules, noncommutative-algebra

> If $R$ is a ring and $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules (on the same side) for which the rings $End_R(M)$, $End_R(N)$, and $End_R(M \oplus N)$ are commutative, must $Hom_R(M,N)$ and $Hom_R(N,M)$ vanish?

One case where the question has a positive answer is when $R$ is the ring $\mathbf{Z}$ and $M$ and $N$ are (possibly infinite) cyclic groups. Indeed, a finitely generated abelian group has a commutative endomorphism ring if and only if it is cyclic, and $M \oplus N$ is cyclic if and only if $M$ and $N$ are finite cyclic groups of coprime orders, or one of them is trivial and the other one is infinite. Then, if $M$ and $N$ are finite cyclic groups of coprime orders, there cannot be any nonzero homomorphism between them in either direction, so the answer is "yes" in this case.

Answer (score 4):

We can write an endomorphism of $M\oplus N$ as a matrix
$$\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D}$$
where $A\in\textrm{Hom}(M,M)$, $A\in\textrm{Hom}(M,N)$, $C\in\textrm{Hom}(N,M)$
and $C\in\textrm{Hom}(N,N)$. Suppose $B\in\textrm{Hom}(M,N)$ is not zero. Then the
endomorphisms with matrices
$$\pmatrix{I&0\\0&0}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\pmatrix{0&B\\0&0}$$
fail to commute.

Comment: You meant to say $B \in Hom(M,N)$ and $D \in Hom(N,N)$, right?